# Only last rows contain hyperlink

Tags: c#, hyperlink

I am making a table in which I add a dynamic hyperlink.

The only problem is that it only shows at the last row. I looked around on the forums but could not find anything close to this problem.

```
int index = 0;

int index2 = 0;
string Error = "";

TableCell TCell = new TableCell();
TableRow TRij = new TableRow();

OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString);
try
{
    OleDbCommand SqlQuerry = new OleDbCommand("SELECT naam, omschrijving,prijs,Productnummer FROM Producten WHERE categorie = 3 ", Conn);
    Conn.Open();
    OleDbDataAdapter reader = new OleDbDataAdapter(SqlQuerry);
    DataTable DataBase = new DataTable();
    DataColumnCollection column = DataBase.Columns;
    reader.Fill(DataBase);
    HyperLink Test = new HyperLink();
    int[] Nummers = new int[DataBase.Rows.Count];
    DataBase.Columns.Add("meer info");
    DataBase.Columns.Add("voeg toe aan winkelwagen");
    foreach (DataColumn coll in DataBase.Columns)
    {
        if (coll.Caption == "Productnummer") {

        }
        else
        {
            TCell = new TableCell();
            TCell.Text = coll.Caption;
            TRij.Cells.Add(TCell);

        }
    }

    TBProducten.Rows.Add(TRij);
    while (DataBase.Rows.Count > index)
    {
        TRij = new TableRow();
        TBProducten.Rows.Add(TRij);
        while (index2 < DataBase.Columns.Count - 3){


                TCell = new TableCell();
                TCell.Text = DataBase.Rows[index].ItemArray[index2].ToString();
                TRij.Cells.Add(TCell);
                index2++;                            
        }
        Test.ID = index.ToString();
        Test.NavigateUrl = "~/Product.aspx?q=" + DataBase.Rows[index].ItemArray[index2].ToString();
        Test.Text = "Klik hier voor meer informatie";
        TCell = new TableCell();
        TCell.Controls.Add(Test);
        TRij.Cells.Add(TCell);
        TBProducten.Rows.Add(TRij);


            //{

            //    TCell = new TableCell();
            //    TCell.Text = reader.GetValue(index2).ToString();
            //    TRij.Cells.Add(TCell);

            //}


        index2 = 0;
        index++;
    }
}
catch (Exception E)
{
    Error = E.Message.ToString();
    lblError.Text = Error;
}
finally
{
    Conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Just a guess, but it looks like you're trying to add the same control to multiple table cells. It's likely that you can't do that. Instead, you'll have to create a new hyperlink for each cell that you want to place on in.

Comment: the problem is that the table is dynamic

Comment: as Jim says, just move the new hyperlink code inside of the while loop right before where you are creating the new id for it.

Comment: hey thank guys thanks to you i could make my program happen :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that in the loop i didn't declare

HyperLink Test = new HyperLink();

thats why there was only one.